# have a fragment in new page in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity with a button, that this button will transfer me to a fragment. The code that I used is:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_laptop)

    btnprice = findViewById<Button>(R.id.price)

    btnprice.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick (v: View) {
            val fm = supportFragmentManager
            val ft = fm.beginTransaction()
            ft.replace(R.id.fab, Pricefragment())
            ft.commit()
        }
    }
    )
}
```

The point is that I want to have the fragment in a new page. Right now, it will show the fragment on the activity page, while the layout is inherited from activity. 
How can I have the fragment in new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use viewpager or Androidx Navigation

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-android-viewpager

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started